# How to define wcf application to another port

Tags: wcf, configuration, .net-4.0, port

I'm trying to get another port for my service application,
and I found the web config empty from the port configurations.
Where can I define the port of my wcf application ,add new endpoint etc.
P.S : I am using .net 4

Comment: Not very clear.... can you **show us** the contents of your web.config - at least the <system.serviceModel> section - and explain in more detail what you want to achieve??

Comment: How are you hosting or is this out of Visual Studio during development?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define port in web.config. The port can be defined only for self hosted services. For IIS hosted service, a port is defined by Web site hosting your service application.

You probably don't see any configuration because .NET 4.0 offers simplified configuration model where default configuration is applied. You can create your own configuration in the same way as in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of your endpoints is typically done in your application's config file - either an `app.config` for your console or Winforms app, or your `web.config` for a web app.

You can define many things in config:

- your endpoint address
- your binding used
- your service contract offered by that service endpoint

Whether or not you can define your **port** in the config depends on how you host your service - if you host it in IIS/WAS, then you cannot define the port - this will be handled by IIS. If you self-host (in a console app, Windows NT Service or something), then you **can** define your port in config.